# How to dynamically create new array each time a function is being called?

Tags: c++

Each time the function is being called, i want to create a new array with a new name to save the results and later compare different arrays to check if they are the same. I want the arrays being created with different but uniformed names each time like array1, array2.... And will "static" keyword work because these arrays need to remain in the memory after the function returned.

something like this

```
func()
{static char array1[10];
 .......
}
```

Comment: What about [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)? It does the job for you

Comment: in this context `static` means that your array isn't allocated on the stack (ie, when `func` is called), but rather in the data section of your program, but with visibility limited to `func`. The feature you describe isn't possible in C++ that way.

Comment: Now here's the important question: how do you plan to use these arrays? Do you wish to access them by their names in the code, eg. `array9[5] =  3;` ? Or do you merely wish to check if they exist? If the later, you will need some sort of container to store and index them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a static vector of arrays:

```
void func()
{
    using array_type = std::array<char,10>;
    static std::vector<array_type> store;

    array_type your_array;
    // ... fill your_array
    store.push_back(your_array);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to put a space in between `> >` anymore in C++11 and above.

Comment: sure, but that's one thing I'll continue also in C++11. It doesn't hurt, and you get slightly more pre-C++11 compability (e.g. if one decides to change the array above into a vector and switch to an old compiler, that is a thing you don't have to worry about...)